# The Django test client: polls app part 5 NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, xcode, helper

I am following the [polls app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial05/) and I am copying everything making sure I have 100% the same code they have but when I use

```
response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'));
```

I get a huge error and none of the notes are making sense to me. I was told by someone it has to do with my **views.py** but I looked and the Django site and it is 100% the same as mine. This was the error I got:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pools/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$']
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Images of code and/or errors can be helpful, but an even more helpful step is to copy/paste the text of the error itself.  The amount of mental bandwidth this saves others when trying to answer your question can add up over time.  See here for further community discussion on this point- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to specify the GET parameter named **question_id** on your URL.

> The [**NoReverseMatch**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#django.urls.NoReverseMatch) exception is raised by **django.urls** when a matching
>   URL in your URLconf cannot be identified based on the parameters
>   supplied.

The error said you have to provide a question id. I used 1 as an example.

```
http://localhost:8000/pools/1/vote/
```

Comment: `def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))` .           I think it is in here I'm not sure.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to have to it is readable on here I tried like 5 times

Comment: You may always edit your own question. I suggest you add a section at its bottom and place anything else you want there.

Comment: here is my Git repo maybe you can help me on there it would help a lot https://bitbucket.org/a1land/testrepo.git

Comment: I took a look and still thinking that you are **not fulfilling the request correctly**. Forget about the code. Your's views.py looks fine. The problem is how you write your URL in your browser.

Comment: Can you please update your question with your urls.py file ?

Comment: hello, when I load my server and run the site it runs fine its when I test my code on the terminal is where I'm having these problems =/ would that still be a problem?